# How to get the treeview to work with images

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have a treeview that shows an image based on what the file type is. here is the code for the constructor:

```
public FileTreeItem(File f)
{
    super(f);
            String str = getFileExtension(f);
            String imagePath = !f.isFile() ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/packageFull.png":
                    str.equals("is") ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/instructionset.png":
                    str.equals("dt") ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/datatype.png":
                    str.equals("main") ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/startfile.png":
                    str.equals("asm") ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/assemblyfile.png":
                    str.equals("png") || str.equals("jpg") || str.equals("bmp") ? "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/imagefile.png":
                    "file:ca/forgetech/ide/assets/images/blankfile.png";
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image(imagePath));
            setGraphic(imgView);
    }

    private String getFileExtension(File f)
    {
        int i = f.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".");
        String ret = "";
        if(i != -1)
        {
            ret = f.getAbsolutePath().substring(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue with that code? Could be that you're using a substring starting with `.` but not including it in the strings you use with `equals`. Also this would be a lot easier to read, if you used a `switch` or better still a `Map` for your case distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. The "file:" part before the image location is causing an issue with how it works. You don't put it before image locations.